# Template parameter pack attribute

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

We have template class:

```
template<int i>
class A
{
...
};
```

But how to declare packer of template classes:

```
template<int... is>
Pack
{

private:
    A<is...> attrs;
};
```

Or howto have collection of classes A?

Answer (score 9):

Using `std::tuple`, by example

```
#include <tuple>

template <int i>
class A
 { };

template <int... is>
class Pack
 { std::tuple<A<is>...>  attrs; };

int main()
 {
   Pack<2,3,5,7,11,13>  p;
 }
```

Another way can be through inheritance

```
template <int i>
class A
 { };

template <int... is>
class Pack : A<is>...
 { };

int main()
 {
   Pack<2,3,5,7,11,13>  p;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The best approach I know is to use a **type list**:

```
template<class...> struct type_list{};

template<int...Is>
using a_pack = type_list<A<Is>...>;
```

With type list, it is really easy to perform transformation or 
make operation on each members. For example let's create a type_list of std:vector with the previous code:

```
template<class> struct vectors_of;

template<class...As> struct vectors_of<type_list<As...>>{
     using type=type_list<std::vector<As>...>;
};
using vectors_of_a = typename vectors_of<a_pack<1,2>>::type;
```

Their is a lot of documentation about type lists. This is one of the basic tools
of meta-programmers since this book: *Modern C++ Design* (which uses pre-c++11). With C++11, it is even easier to use it.